# Preview-latex images wrong locations. (offset by 1)

Tags: emacs, auctex, mac

I've been writing some results with various equations in align blocks using latex. I've recently begun using AUCTeX with its preview functionality, which is really cool. Things start out great, but as my document gets longer, at some point, preview-latex breaks. Some one preview image in the middle of the document ends up blank, and then the remaining images in the document are misaligned, i.e. each preview image corresponds to the markup of the previous preview section.

e.g.

> markup 1: correct
>
> ...
>
> markup k: blank box
>
> markup k+1: shows markup k
>
> markup k+2: shows markup k+1
>
> ...
>
> markup n: shows markup n-1

When I run pdfLaTeX on my document, it compiles with no problems or warnings.

So far, I've found that I can avoid this problem if I  use `C-c C-p C-r` section by section. But I'd prefer to be able to just `C-c C-p C-b` at times.

My system is OS X 10.10 running Emacs 24.4.1 using AUCTeX 11.88.8 installed by melpa. I've customized AUCTeX to preview inline math and block math (i.e. modified defaults to not preview section headings, though whether or not headings are previewed doesn't affect this bug).

Comment: Same prolem here.  Linux Debian Jessie, Emacs 24.4.1, AUCTeX 11.89.1.

Comment: Same. Ubuntu 15.10, stock Emacs (24.5.1)

Comment: Apparently it is a bug of preview-latex on the new Debian/OS X kernel. Anyone to report the bug?